# MongoDB/Mongoose: Can't put simplest MapReduce to work

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, grouping, mongoose

Hello all I'm trying to do is to get the count of each distinct departmentType:

```
fnMap = function() { 
  emit(this.departments.departmentType, {typeCount:1} ); 
} 

fnReduce = function(key, values) { 
  var result = {typeCount: 0}; 
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    result.typeCount += value.brandCount;
  });

  return result;             
};


var command = {
mapreduce : "clients", 
query     : {"departments.departmentType": {$exists: true}},
map       : fnMap.toString(), 
reduce    : fnReduce.toString(),    
    //sort: {"departments.departmentType":1}, 
    out: {inline: 1}   
};

mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(command, function(err, dbres) {

    });
```

When executing the command, dbres.documents[0].results only contains 1 item with the total number of departmentTypes, instead of several items one for each departmentType with its count.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Also, when I uncomment the SORT line, I get error "db assertion failure: could not create cursor over...", I believe the field name is written correctly.

Comment: What is brandCount in reduce?  Looks like a typo.  Should be typeCount

Comment: I'll add corrected mapReduce to my answer, in case it helps but you don't need mapReduce here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose v3 has now a `Model.mapreduce()` function [(see doc)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-mapReduce).

The full example shown is:

```
var o = {};
o.map = function () { emit(this.name, 1) }
o.reduce = function (k, vals) { return vals.length }
o.out = { replace: 'createdCollectionNameForResults' }
o.verbose = true;
User.mapReduce(o, function (err, model, stats) {
  console.log('map reduce took %d ms', stats.processtime)
  model.find().where('value').gt(10).exec(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
  });
})
```

The problem with count i believe is because in your fnReduce() function you are summit the results instead of displaying them in an array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reponse but I don't know what you mean by "in your fnReduce() function you are summit the results instead of displaying them in an array." Could you please let me know how it should be?

I checked the syntax for Mongoose 3 but I think I'll have the same problem as I have now if the issue is related to my reduce function.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've made some progress but not working yet: In my previous example, if I "emit" something like this.field1 it works, grouping by all different values of field1. However any field deeper than 1st level fails: this.field1.field1a fails. Any idea why?

Comment: i'm trying to run this in the shell (without mongoose), can you please update your question with some sample data of the collection?

Comment: Hi, I've created a new post here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753440/mapreduce-aggregation-group-by-a-value-in-a-nested-document>

Comment: Hi, I sort of resolved this using aggregation, please see post here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753440/mapreduce-aggregation-group-by-a-value-in-a-nested-document/12782154#12782154)

Still having some problems inclusing fields in the results, so I opened a new thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782105/field-not-showing-in-mongoose-aggregation)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
db.clients.distinct("departments.departmentType")
```

That will give an array with all the distinct departmentType values.

There were two problems in your map/reduce.  One is brandCount in reduce rather than typeCount.  But more importantly, you are trying to emit once per document, when you need to emit once per department array element.   Corrected (and slightly simplified) code:

```
> fnMap = function () {
    this.departments.forEach(
       function (d) {
          emit(d.departmentType, 1);
       }
    );
}
> fnReduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = 0;
    values.forEach(
       function (value) {result += value;});
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I made some progress thanks to them. When I set 
   `out:"NewCollection"`
it successfully creates the collection. 

However I'd like to run it as 
   out: {inline: 1} 

When I do this, I then try to use the results like this:

mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(command, function(err, dbres) {
 dbres.find({"value":{$gte: 5}}).exec(function(err, departments) {  
...
    });

However I get that find() is not a valid method. Is this the right way?

Sorry for jumping between all these possible solutions, I'm trying all of them but no luck so far.

Thank you.

Comment: why no luck?  Just use distinct - you don't need map/reduce unless you need the counts (and then it's easier to use aggregation framework).  if you want results inline then they are not in any collection so you don't need find.  inline will return a document with array "result" which has result documents.