# mapReduce/Aggregation: Group by a value in a nested document

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose, aggregation-framework

imagine I have a collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "departments": [
             {"departmentType":"01",
              "departmentHead":"Peter"},
             {"departmentType":"02",
              "departmentHead":"John"}
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "10281",
  "city": "LOS ANGELES",
  "state": "CA",
  "departments": [
             {"departmentType":"02",
              "departmentHead":"Joan"},
             {"departmentType":"03",
              "departmentHead":"Mary"}
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "10284",
  "city": "MIAMI",
  "state": "FL",
  "department": [
  "departments": [
             {"departmentType":"01",
              "departmentHead":"George"},
             {"departmentType":"02",
              "departmentHead":"Harry"}
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get a count per departmentType, something like:

```
[{"departmentType":"01", "dCount":2},
 {"departmentType":"02", "dCount":3},
 {"departmentType":"03", "dCount":1}
]
```

For this, I've tried almost everything already, but all examples I find online are easier ones where the group by is done over a field at the root level of the document. Instead, here I'm trying to group by departmentType, and that seems to break everything I found so far.

Any ideas on how to do this using Mongoose's aggregation implementation or mapreduce?

Ideally, I'd like to exclude all departmentTypes with count <= 1 and sort the results by departmentType.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that last department is correct? it doesn't look valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to $unwind the departments array which will create a document for each entry in the array so you can aggregate them in the pipeline.

Unfortunately, you can't pre-filter departmentTypes <= 1 because $size will only take a an exact value, but you can filter it out of the results. It's not great, but it works. This example pre-filters only those records with EXACTLY 2 departments, but it's for demo only, you probably want to drop the first $match because we filter out <=1 with the second $match on the results later on;

```
db.runCommand({
    aggregate: "so",
    pipeline: [
        {   // filter out only records with 2 departments
            $match: {
                departments: { $size: 2 }
            }
        },
        // unwind - create a doc for each department in the array
        { $unwind: "$departments" },
        {   // aggregate sum of departments by type
            $group: {
                _id: "$departments.departmentType",
                count: { $sum: 1 },
            }
        },
        {   // filter out departments with <=1
            $match: {
                count: { $gt: 1 },
            }
        },
        {   // rename fields as per example
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                departmentType: "$_id",
                dCount: "$count",
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Note that I've also assumed that your previous json sample has a typo, and "department" doesn't actually exist. This code will work assuming all the documents have the same schema as the first two.

Feel free to drop the first $match, and the last $project if you're not bothered about the actual field names you get.

Comment: Hi, ok tried this, couple of prob silly things: Rewrote syntax to `mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(...` and added `, function(err, dbres) {
   if (err)
    throw err;
   else
    console.log(dbres);
  
  });´ at the end to catch the results.

It then said that ´ aggregate: "so",´ NO SUCH CMD: "aggregate".

Any idea?

I did reuse the first $match: 

´$match: {
   departmentThatExist : {"departments.departmentType": {$exists: true}}` to exclude the ones without departmentType. 
     }

Comment: Are you using an older version of MongoDB than 2.2 ? The aggregation stuff didn't ship until the current latest version.

Comment: that first $match on $size is not a correct filter given the problem statement.  the last $match will get rid of departmentTyped which only have one occurrence.  there should also be a $sort at the end, given original requirements.

Comment: your comment about pre-filtering departments with only one type isn't correct at all - there is no way to prefilter but _not_ because of $size of array, but because the count of each departmentType (across all documents) isn't known until after the $group phase of the aggregation.

Comment: Ah. You're right. It wasn't the number of departments he wanted <=1 it was the value of departmntType. Subtle distinction. In which case yes, that can't be prefiltered at all.